# Adding Markers to Google map from json Array

Tags: arrays, json, for-loop

> This is my poor code

```
function loaddata() {
            var url = "http://localhost/Geocording/api.php";
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                var  json = data
                for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {

                    var val = json[i],
                      var  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lng);

                    console.log(latLng)
                }

            });

        }
```

> Im trying to get details from my own api using json array.
>   but its not working.

```
{"location":[{"name":"Home 1","lat":"6.824367","lng":"80.034523","type":"1"},{"name":"Grid Tower 1","lat":"6.82371292","lng":"80.03451942","type":"1"},{"name":"Power Station A","lat":"6.82291793","lng":"80.03417451","type":"1"}],"success":1}
```

> This is json response from my api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make things clear first then apply it. First read JSON clearly then go on to apply it in your code. This is the working code.

```
 function loaddata() {
        var url = "http://localhost/Geocording/api.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var  json = data['location'];
            for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {

               var val = json[i];
               var  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(val['lat'], val['lng']);

                console.log(latLng)
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Your welcome, but i would suggest you to read JSON clearly then try to apply it yourself then only you are going to understand things.